# C# code for Rest API read only that will output to csv

Tags: c#, .net, rest, csv

Updated and still showing two errors.

The documentation I was given isn't the best so I do not believe Result/Ireadonlylist/HistValueResonseDTO are define unless it is defined in one of the dependencies.   I tried the following code and it came up two errors.   1. "Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   CS1061  'HistValueResponseDto' does not contain a definition for 'Tags' and no accessible extension method 'Tags' accepting a first argument of type 'HistValueResponseDto' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ConsoleApp7 C:\Users\jzala\source\repos\ConsoleApp7\Program.cs  89  Active"   and this one.  Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object?' ConsoleApp7 C:\Users\jzala\source\repos\ConsoleApp7\Program.cs  89  Active

Here is the full code.

```
        namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Numerics;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using CSharpFunctionalExtensions;
    using CsvHelper;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using Scada.OneView.Api.Client;
    using Scada.OneView.Api.Client.Abstractions;
    using Scada.OneView.Api.Client.Models.HistData;
    using Serilog;
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Initialize parameters
            const string oneViewUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/oneview4";
            const string authenticationUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/oneview4/auth/";
            const string username = "XXXX";
            const string password = "XXXXXXX";
            const string logFilePath = @"C:\Users\jzala\Documents\PivotGenPy\test7.txt";

            // Initialize logger
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.File(logFilePath)
            .CreateLogger();

            // Put OneView Authentication URL and username/password here
            var authenticationSettings = new OneViewAuthenticationSettings
            {
                AuthUrl = authenticationUrl,
                Username = username,
                Password = password,
                AuthenticationType = AuthenticationType.IdentityAuthentication,
            };

            // Put OneView URL here
            var oneviewSettings = new OneViewClientSettings
            {
                OneViewUrl = oneViewUrl
            };

            // Create single factory for one OneView, using oneview and authentication settings
            using var oneviewClientFactory = new OneViewClientFactory(
            oneviewSettings,
            authenticationSettings,
            Log.Logger);


            //Historical Values
            var unitGuid = new Guid("d6f49127-d710-4730-9aa1-d44846fd5537");
            var tags = new List<string>() { "WCNV.GriA2_10m_Max", "WCNV.GriA2_10m_Min", "WCNV.GriA2_10m_Std" };
            var dateFrom = new DateTime(2024, 3, 1, 10, 0, 0);
            var DateTO = new DateTime(2024, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0);
            const byte amountOfEvents = 90;


            IOneViewClient oneViewClient = oneviewClientFactory.CreateInstance();

            Result<IReadOnlyList<HistValueResponseDto>> tagResults = await oneViewClient.GetHistTagsAsync(unitGuid, tags, dateFrom,
                DateTO, 2, 2);


            if (tagResults.IsFailure)
            {
                // An error occured
                //Log.Logger.Error(tagResults.Error);
                return;
            }

            // Path of output CSV File
            string csvFilePath = "output.csv";

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(csvFilePath))
            {

                sw.WriteLine("Tags,Count");

                // Iterates over the results and writes them into the file
                foreach (var d in tagResults.Value)
                {
                    // Assuming d.Tags is a string and d.Count is an int
                    sw.WriteLine($"{d.Tags},{d.Count}");
                }



                // Parse the response body
                //var dataObjects = tagResults;
                //foreach (var d in dataObjects)
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine("{0},{0}", d.Tags,d.Count);
                // }

                //Log.Logger.Information("Historical events from OneView");
                //tagResults.Value.ToList().ForEach(tag => 
                //Log.Logger.Information(tagResults);
                // Log.Logger.Information("Finish reading");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

End of New Code

Comment: I am not really familiar with the `Result` class but I think you are trying to loop through a variable that doesn't contain a list of items. Maybe try to loop through `dataObjects.Value` or something like that.

Comment: What Azure DevOps client API are you calling in the C# code? And what data do you want to fetch using the client API?

Comment: I am confused how you can use the `await` keyword with C# 2.0 but anyway did you try converting the second line to `IReadOnlyList<HistValueResponseDto> tagResults = ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help everyone.  After some digging in I found the structure to be a mess.  Multiple nested arrays/lists.   Anyways,  incase someone else has an issue here is the code the unpacked it.

```
        var dateFrom = new DateTime(2024, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    var DateTO = new DateTime(2024, 3, 11, 0, 0, 0);
    const byte amountOfEvents = 90;
    IOneViewClient oneViewClient = oneviewClientFactory.CreateInstance();
    Result<IReadOnlyList<HistValueResponseDto>> tagResult = await oneViewClient.GetHistTagsAsync(unitGuid, tags, dateFrom,
        DateTO, 10, 0);
    if (tagResult.IsFailure)
    {
        // An error occured
        Log.Logger.Error(tagResult.Error);
        return;
    }
    //Log.Logger.Information("Historical events from OneView");
    tagResult.Value.ToList().ForEach(Value =>
        Value.Values.ToList().ForEach(Values =>
       Log.Logger.Information("{@Unit},{@tagname},{@Timestamp},{@Value}", unitGuid, Value.TagName, Values.Timestamp, Values.Value)));
}
Log.Logger.Information("done");
```

}